# nextTuple() is called infinite times using BaseRichSpout on Storm

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-storm

I implemented simple Storm topology having single spout and a bolt running on local cluster mode.

for some reason  nextTuple() of the spout is called more than once.

Any idea why?

code:

spout:

```
public class CommitFeedListener extends BaseRichSpout {
    private SpoutOutputCollector outputCollector;
    private List<String> commits;

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("commit"));
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Map configMap,
                     TopologyContext context,
                     SpoutOutputCollector outputCollector) {
        this.outputCollector = outputCollector;
    }

    **//that method is invoked more than once**
    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {

            outputCollector.emit(new Values("testValue"));

    }
}
```

bolt:

```
public class EmailExtractor extends BaseBasicBolt {
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("email"));
    }
    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple,
                        BasicOutputCollector outputCollector) {
        String commit = tuple.getStringByField("commit");
        System.out.println(commit);        
    }  
}
```

running configuration:

```
public class LocalTopologyRunner {
    private static final int TEN_MINUTES = 600000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("commit-feed-listener", new CommitFeedListener());
                builder
        .setBolt("email-extractor", new EmailExtractor())
                .shuffleGrouping("commit-feed-listener");
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setDebug(true);
        StormTopology topology = builder.createTopology();
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("github-commit-count-topology",
                config,
                topology);
        Utils.sleep(TEN_MINUTES);
        cluster.killTopology("github-commit-count");
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
}
```

thanks all,
ray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nextTuple() is called in an infinite loop by design. It is made like this to use for instance dirty checks against an external resource (database, stream, IO, etc).

You should sleep a while to prevent CPU spamming with backtype.storm.utils.Utils if you have nothing to do in nextTuple()

```
Utils.sleep(pollIntervalInMilliseconds);
```

Storm is a real-time processing architecture, so it is indeed the correct behaviour. Check some samples to see how to implement a spout according to your needs.

Comment: Yes but if I have an input file for instance. as soon as I finish reading it I dont want it to re-process it all over again. how could you avoid it?

Comment: Just sleep each time with a high millis value to prevent CPU spam after you sent your value once. But a spout, as a real-time checker, will always call the method by design.

Comment: But it doesnt help me if I sleep. I want to know when I finished to read the file for example.. or a list. how I can know that if that method keeps calling over and over..?

Comment: @rayman, you should describe your use case first. You can't bend Storm design to your use, but you can design your topology according to your needs. I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I understand you. I read the docs. And got it right this time.

Answer (score 0):

How about create some flag and set it when necessary?

```
if (completed) {
    try {
        Utils.sleep(pollIntervalInMilliseconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Do nothing
    }
    return;
}
```